# Replace images with thumbnail on failed - swiftUI

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui

I am fetching images from Firebase storage, if there is no image on firebase, I want to show thumbnail,

Thats where I get the error

```
if let error = error {
          Swift.print(error)
      }
```

Here is my thumbnail

```
Image("shoePlaceHolder")
.resizable()
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

Here is the complete code

```
func getFullImageURL() {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storagePath = "gs://on-switch.appspot.com/main/\(season)/"
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: storagePath)        
        let formattedImageURL = imageURL.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file:///", with: "")
        let ref = storageRef.child(formattedImageURL)
        ref.downloadURL { url, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    Swift.print(error)
                } else if let url = url {
                    fullImageURL = url
                } else {
                    Swift.print("No url and no error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var content: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                headerView()
                HStack {
                    AsyncImage(url: $fullImageURL.wrappedValue) { image in
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    } placeholder: {
                        Image("shoePlaceHolder")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    }.frame(width: 260, height: 180)
                        .onAppear(perform: getFullImageURL)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        titleView()
                        subtitleView()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding()
            OnDivider()
                .padding(.horizontal)
            SectionView(leadingView: {
                Text("\(variants.count) variants")
                    .secondaryText()
            }, trailingView: {
                Image(systemName: "rectangle.expand.vertical")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.secondaryLabel))
            }).padding()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this line to invoke the listener for `fullImageURL`

```
 fullImageURL = nil
```

and the complete code will look like this:

```
func getFullImageURL() {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storagePath = "gs://on-switch.appspot.com/main/\(season)/"
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: storagePath)        
        let formattedImageURL = imageURL.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file:///", with: "")
        let ref = storageRef.child(formattedImageURL)
        ref.downloadURL { url, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    Swift.print(error)
                    fullImageURL = nil
                } else if let url = url {
                    fullImageURL = url
                } else {
                    Swift.print("No url and no error")
                    fullImageURL = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no image was shown as an error, you just need to focus on the error. Something like:

```swift
if error.localizedDescription == NoImageErrorString { // NoImageErrorString is something you can find in Firebase code
    // show thumbnail here
} else {
    // your original code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var url: URL?
    
    func getFullImageURL() {
        self.url = URL(string: "")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            } placeholder: {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            .frame(width: 260, height: 180)
            .onAppear(perform: getFullImageURL)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
   }
}
```

If you want to use a custom image, make sure `shoePlaceHolder` is added to the project `Assets`.

```
Image("shoePlaceHolder")
```

.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am downloaded images in a block, I have to return a value to from getFullImageURL and show it in var content: some View. Your solution works for simple case.

Comment: It should work for your scenario too, unless I missed the essence of the question. You can wrap the `AsyncImage` in a `if let url {}` block if you want to display a placeholder only if the url does not return an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ***struct*** instead of a *@State*, *@Published* or whatever you're using to store *fullImageURL*.

Something like:

```
struct ImageWithErrorPlaceholder {
    var fullImageURL: URL?
    var showErrorPlaceholder: Bool = false
}
```

So you can simply inform the URL and the error as needed:

```
ref.downloadURL { url, error in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error {
            imageWithErrorPlaceholder.showErrorPlaceholder = true
            Swift.print(error)
        } else if let url = url {
            imageWithErrorPlaceholder.fullImageURL = url
        } else {
            Swift.print("No url and no error")
        }
    }
}
```

That way you can display a different placeholder in case of error or no placeholder at all, depending or your needs:

```
AsyncImage(url: imageWithErrorPlaceholder.fullImageURL) { image in
    image
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
} placeholder: {
    if imageWithErrorPlaceholder.showErrorPlaceholder {
        Image("shoePlaceHolder")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```